# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' not fixed by javaxb or hibernate dependencies

Tags: spring-data-jpa, java-11

I realize this has been asked time and time again here but after trying the fixes from multiple responses I am still running into this problem.

I'm receiving an error when I try to run my spring API stating:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at com.max.rocketLeagueAPI.Main.main(Main.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:179) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my pom file. I have tried adding jaxb-api, hibernate-entitymanager, hibernate-core, and combinations of the three without any luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.max</groupId>
    <artifactId>rocketLeagueAPI</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.3.1</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my model class:

```
package com.max.rocketLeagueAPI.Models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "car_id")
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String rarity;
    private String platform;
    @Column(name = "img_url")
    private String imgUrl;
    private boolean free;
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Timestamp updatedAt;

    public Car() {}

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getRarity() {
        return this.rarity;
    }

    public String getPlatform() {
        return this.platform;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return this.imgUrl;
    }

    public boolean isFree() {
        return this.free;
    }

    public Timestamp getUpdatedAt() {
        return this.updatedAt;
    }
}
```

Here is the table I am connecting to (or trying to)

```
mysql> describe cars;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| car_id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| name       | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| rarity     | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| platform   | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| img_url    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| free       | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 1                 |                             |
| updated_at | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And my interface:

```
package com.max.rocketLeagueAPI.Repositories;

import com.max.rocketLeagueAPI.Models.Car;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer> {
    // car filters
    List<Car> findByPlatform(String platform);
    List<Car> findByRarity(String rarity);
    List<Car> findByFree(boolean isFree);
    List<Car> findByRarityAndFree(String rarity, boolean isFree);
}
```

and my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rocketLeagueAPI
spring.datasource.username=max
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I'm following a guide on writing a spring api but even when I use the exact code from the guide I get the same error. Is anything missing from what I have or annotated incorrectly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much more research I found the issue and fix. javaxb is no longer supported in the jdk11 so these dependencies need to be added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

application.properties also required:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Hope this helps anyone else on running into this issue!